# Lookup multiple values for a report summary with conditional statements to a single textbox

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to create a shipping report in Access which is really just a summary of products on a job with a bit of additional relevant information on each product. I have a `Products` table and a `ProductVars` table which link using a `ProductID` number.

I'm trying to lookup 2 variables in the `ProductVars` table called `FinishedLeft` and `FinishedRight` and get their corresponding values.

I would then do conditional statements where the report would show that the product is either `"L"` (for finished left), `"R"` (for finished right), `"B"` (for finished both), or just blank if no finished ends.

I've created a query called `qryFinishedEnds` and use a `dlookup` but I'm not sure how I would code this to look specifically at a field value.

The following statement entered in Control Source only gives me the result of the first record in the query.

```
=DLookUp("[Value]","qryFinishedEnds","[ProductID] =" & [ProductID])
```

I've also tried entering code in VBA and assigning the value to a text box when the report loads but I can't get that to work right either because it just repeats the same value for every record.

Any thoughts on how I could do this?

Editing this post for clarification.

According to the following link, it says I can have multiple criteria in a DLookup string.
http://access-excel.tips/access-dlookup-lookup-multiple-criteria/

Here is what I'm trying to accomplish.
=IIf(DLookUp("[Value]","qryFinishedEnds","[ProductID] =" & [ProductID] And "[Name] ='FinishedLeft'")=1

And

IIf(DLookUp("[Value]","qryFinishedEnds","[ProductID] =" & [ProductID] And "[Name] ='FinishedRight'")=0 Then “L”

Elseif

IIf(DLookUp("[Value]","qryFinishedEnds","[ProductID] =" & [ProductID] And "[Name] ='FinishedLeft'")=1

And

IIf(DLookUp("[Value]","qryFinishedEnds","[ProductID] =" & [ProductID] And "[Name] ='FinishedRight'")=1 Then “B”

Elseif

IIf(DLookUp("[Value]","qryFinishedEnds","[ProductID] =" & [ProductID] And "[Name] ='FinishedLeft'")=0

And

IIf(DLookUp("[Value]","qryFinishedEnds","[ProductID] =" & [ProductID] And "[Name] ='FinishedRight'")=1 Then “R”

Else

“blank”

Of course, this is full of errors but hopefully, you can understand what I'm getting at.

If there is an easier way than Dlookup, then please let me know.

Here is what my query looks like.

[query for Dlookup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxDQS.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried `=DLookUp("[Value]","qryFinishedEnds","[ProductID] =" & [Report]![ProductID]` ?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns - shouldn't that be `Reports!reportname!ProductID`? Is the expression in textbox in Detail section? The posted expression should work. Edit question to post example of data in query as well as the SQL. Why DLookup()? Can you join the query to report RecordSource? Where are conditional statements?

Comment: I've tried adding [Report]! to the string but it just gives me the same result.  Currently, it's just returns the first match so I get a result just zero's and ones on my report. It doesn't tell me which result it is returning.

Comment: I'm just entering the dlookup under the properties of the textbox under control source and thought maybe I could add an extra condition for each variable which I haven't been able to write yet.  (ex. If FinishedLeft=1 then... , If FinishedRight=1 then... etc.)  If I add the table to my existing record source query then it duplicates all my products on the report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure my explanation is worded poorly but here's what I figured out.  I was trying to figure out how to use a dlookup with multiple criteria.  I ended up having 2 text boxes side by side on my report.  One for left finished ends and one for right finished ends.  For the left finished ends, I added the following string in the control source of the text box.

```
=IIf(DLookUp("[Value]","PRODUCTVARS","[Name]='FinishedLeft' AND ProductID=" & [ProductID]),"L","")
```

For the other text box, it's the same string except that the Name='FinishedRight'.

I was hoping to have a single text box that when both ends are finished, would show either an "L", "R", or "B" for both but instead, the report will show either "L", "R", or "LR" which will be fine for now.

I'm also needing to show the same information on other reports so would be nice to eventually have VBA code or write a function or something.

Answer (score 0):

> I've also tried entering code in VBA and assigning the value to a text
>   box when the report loads but I can't get that to work right either
>   because it just repeats the same value for every record.

That's a normal behavior, function Dlookup only returns "first match".

If you want to only display informations relative to a specific record you should use Access report tool, but it won't be editable.

Comment: Your comment about only being able to return "first match" answers my question to a certain degree.  Dlookup might not be the solution.  I don't quite understand what you mean though about the report tool.  How is using "Access report tool" different from my current report I created in Access?  I don't need the report to be editable because it will look for the same variables all the time.